# AngularJS: How to set ng-model or change scope value from directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have created a directive for input, select, and radio directives.

`<input ng-model="data-ng-model="answers.{{name}}"` is not working

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="que in questions[$state.current.name]">
    <div ng-if="que.QuestionData._fieldType === 'text'" >
        <text-control-dir data-que-obj="que.QuestionData" data-selected-ans="answers[que.QuestionData._attributeName]"></text-control-dir>
    </div>  
    <div ng-if="que.QuestionData._fieldType === 'select'" >
        <select-control-dir data="que.QuestionData"></select-control-dir>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="que.QuestionData._fieldType === 'radio'" >
         <radio-control-dir data="que.QuestionData"></radio-control-dir>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="que.QuestionData._fieldType === 'hidden' && que.QuestionData._attributeName != 'CBQ'" >
         <hidden-control-dir data="que.QuestionData"></hidden-control-dir>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my directive:

```
   function textControlDir()
    {
        return {
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            /*scope: {
                queObj: '=',
                selectedAns: '='
                },*/
            template: '<div class="form-group">\n\
                       <label for="{{queObj._attributeName}}" class="col-sm-5 control-label">{{queObj._text}}</label>\n\
                       <div class="col-sm-6"><input data-ng-model="answers.{{name}}" type="text" name="{{name}}" class="form-control" id="{{id}}" value="{{selectedAns}}"></div>\n\
                       </div>',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs)
            {
                var queObj = scope.que.QuestionData;
                scope.queObj = scope.que.QuestionData; 
                scope.name = queObj._attributeName;
                scope.id = queObj._attributeName;
                var selectedAns = '';
                if(scope.answers)
                {
                   selectedAns = scope.answers[scope.name];
                }
                if(selectedAns && selectedAns != '')
                {
                    scope.selectedAns = selectedAns;
                }
                else
                {
                    scope.selectedAns = scope.queObj._pageAttributes.defaultValue;
                } 
            }
        };
    }
```

How do I dynamically manage the ng-model? I want to map `$scope.answers.{{name}}` when user changes anything in input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can require `ngModel`.

```
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
}
```

Then you can update the ng-model accordingly using       `ngModel.$setViewValue(newValue);`

Below is a simple example on how can `achieve` the same:

http://jsfiddle.net/t2GAS/2/

Comment: I want to set input value in answers.{{name}}

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
 data-ng-model="name"
```

Now in the controller you can do this:

```
$scope.answers.name = name; // <--- the ng-model assigned to answer.name in $scope
```

Comment: Please see this http://plnkr.co/edit/Op1QDwUBECAosPUC7r3N?p=preview how can i introduce controller here. can I do this code in link

Comment: Onchange or blur if I could update $scope.answers.name = name; also this work. but here name id dynamic come from que